# Не с причастием

Tags: причастия, частица-не

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно ли отделять пробелом "не" в словосочетании "не поддерживаемое сообществом". Вроде как из школы помню что-то об этом, что если у причастия есть зависимое слово, то должно писаться раздельно. Я прав?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Не поддерживаемое сообществом.**

Это причастие, так как образовано от переходного глагола несовершенного вида ***поддерживать,*** соответственно, можно применить правило о раздельном  написании НЕ с причастиями при наличии **зависимых слов в Т.п.** (Обозначение производителя действия).

Таким образом, для форм на -МЫЙ требуются дополнительные условия.